# Round last 2 digits of double

Tags: c++, double, rounding

I have a double looking like this:

```
0.04251789
```

And it should look like this:

```
0.04251700
```

No matter what the last two digits are they shall be replaced by 00's;
It is important that the last two digits are not lost but replaced by 00's.

So this:

```
0.042517
```

would be wrong.

What is the fastest way to accomplish that?

Comment: so its just for displaying?

Comment: It is sent to and WebAPI and they want it to have exactly 8 digits. Converting to string is not an option.

Comment: Assuming the API (being web-based) doesn't want unportable binary data, you *have* to convert it to a string sooner or later. And after rounding, just specify the correct field width and precision when creating the string.

Comment: So the API want an 8 digit floatingpoint instead of string?

Comment: If the API wants a double instead of a string, how can it distinguish ‵0.04251700‵ from ‵0.042517‵? By rounding errors?

Comment: *"Converting to string is not an option."* Sounds like you are confusing numbers (e.g. `double`) and their representation as text. As a number, `0.04251700 == 0.042517`, so if you need to see those zeros, you need to choose a representation.

Comment: What you want is not possible.  A double doesn't contain "a certain number of digits".  It contains (typically) 53 bits of mantissa, a sign bit, and 10 bits of exponent.  When you convert this to a string, then you get to specify the number of digits, but *as a double*, there is no difference between 0.5 and 0.50000000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a double looking like this:
>
> 0.04251789
>
> And it should look like this:
>
> 0.04251700

You want to round down to the nearest `1.0 / 1000000`. That can be done like this:

```
double d = 0.04251789;
double rounded = std::floor(f * 1000000) / 1000000;
```

> So this:
>
> 0.042517
>
> would be wrong.

Simply specify the correct precision when you convert the `double` to a string. You want 8 digits, so:

```
std::printf("%.8f", rounded);
```

> Converting to string is not an option.

That's contradictory to your requirement that the number must have trailing zeroes. Trailing (and leading) zeroes are only meaningful in a textual representation of a number.

Answer (score 2):

so here is a c-way, it is not the nicest, but i should do what you want.

```
int main( void ) {
    double number = 0.04251789;
    char buffer[10];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%g", number);
    buffer[8] = '0';
    buffer[9] = '0';
    std::cout << "Converted Number: " << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

output should be `Converted Number: 0.04251700`

I also tried it with string but he seems to cut some digits and i am not sure how to disable this. But if you want to try it the c++ style try the `std::to_string()` method.

Answer (score 1):

as it needs to be string, otherwise you won't be able to display zeros, an c-solution could be:

```
char temp[128];
memset(temp,'\0',sizeof(temp));
sprintf(temp,"%10.8f",0.04251789);
temp[strlen(temp)-1]='0';
temp[strlen(temp)-2]='0';
printf(temp);
```